# Maximise the f_locals dictionary in spyder variable explorer

Tags: python, variables, spyder, local-variables, inspect

This is a Spyder IDE specific question

Spyder IDE does not show local variables of a method in variable explorer, it only shows the global variables. So to get the local variables in variable explorer I use the inspect package in python. Code looks similar to below, program code is rather long and has dataframes, file pointers, Excelwriters and connection object to relational database.

```
local_vars = {}

def databases():
     global local_vars
     #program codes
     local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_locals
```

On double clicking variables in variable explorer we would be able to view the variable in a seperate window as in the image 
[image: variable view]

but this is not working with the `local_vars` dictionary
[image]

How can I remedy this and see `local_vars` in a seperate window ?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Why is it not working? What happens when you do a double-click on `local_vars`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to know the values of local variables is declaring a global dictionary to store the values

```
var = {}

def method():
    var1 = 2
    var2 = 3
    global var
    var['var1'] = var1
    var['var2'] = var2

var1 = var['var1']
var2 = var['var2']
```

This method allows the local variables to be present in variable explorer